# I need to decrypt a file efficiently

Tags: java, encryption, coding-efficiency

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted file with unknown key - the only thing I know about it is that the key is an integer x, 0 <= x < 10<sup>10</sup> (i.e. a maximum of 10 decimal digits).

```
public static String enc(String msg, long key) {
    String ans = "";
    Random rand = new Random(key);
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i = i + 1) {
        char c = msg.charAt(i);
        int s = c;
        int rd = rand.nextInt() % (256 * 256);
        int s2 = s ^ rd;
        char c2 = (char) (s2);
        ans += c2;
    }
    return ans;
}

private static String tryToDecode(String string) {
    String returnedString = "";
    long key;
    String msg = reader(string);
    for (long i = 0; i <= 999999999; i++) {
        System.out.println("decoding message with key + " + i);

        key = i;
        System.out.println("decoding with key: " + i + "\n" + enc(msg, key));

    }
    return returnedString;
}
```

I expect to find the plain text

The program works very slowly, is there any way to make it more efficient?

Comment: *is there any way to make it more efficient?* - Yes: by knowing the key. You could rely on a dictionary instead of bruteforcing (even if I don't think it would be useful in your scenario), but as long as you have to guess a password it will not be efficient.

Comment: Don't `println` in each loop, that will speed it up significantly.

Comment: Your algorithm is just guessing a password each time. As long as you don't have any hints (and the "Maximum of 10 numbers and they must be Natural" is a very good hint already), there's no way to optimize this.

Comment: Along with what @LukePark suggested, have you tried multithreading your code yet?

Comment: Thanks but I don't know the key... any other suggestions? What about threads? (1 thread running from 1-100000, another from 100001-200000 etc...)

Comment: The `key` variable is unneeded, and just using `i` instead would save you one operation each loop.  (Or if you like descriptive variable names, get rid of `i` and make `key` your loop variable.)

Comment: I know the encryption is this:

 public static String enc(String msg, long key)
 {
  String ans = "";
  Random rand = new Random(key);
  for(int i=0;i<msg.length();i=i+1) {
   char c = msg.charAt(i);
   int s = c;
   int rd = rand.nextInt()%(256*256);
   int s2 = s^rd;
   char c2 = (char)(s2);
   ans +=c2;
  }
  return ans;
 }

is it helping?

Comment: @user2932231 Your method, as it is now, doesn't actually return the decoded String.  You never set `returnedString` to anything other than its initial value of `""`.

Comment: @user2932231 Actually, that encoding/decoding method is another thing that can be optimized, and you should probably put it in the question instead of in a comment.

Comment: @user2932231 I have one more question.  Is anything known about the plain text?  Do we know, for example, that it consists of only normal numbers, letters, and punctuation, with no unicode?

Comment: What do you mean by "a Maximum of 10 numbers"?

Comment: @JamesKPolk 10 digits.  (The code shown only checks 9, by the way.)

Comment: If you want to go faster you'll need to understand that [Random](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Random.java?av=f) uses a linear congruential generator and figure out how to search a much smaller set of values for the right answer. One thing to notice is that your encryption method only uses the low-order 16 bits of `Random.nextInt()`.

Comment: @DM: Not generated by Random, but used by Random. Random is used as a stream cipher.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking about improving working code belong on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Parallel Array Operations added in JAVA 8 if you are using Java 8 to achive this.

The best fit for you would be to use Spliterator

```
    public void spliterate() {
    System.out.println("\nSpliterate:");
    int[] src = getData();
    Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = Arrays.spliterator(src);
    spliterator.forEachRemaining( n -> action(n) );
}

public void action(int value) {
    System.out.println("value:"+value);
    // Perform some real work on this data here...
}
```

I am still not clear about your situation. Here some great tutorials and articles to figure out which parallel array operations of java 8 is going to help you ?

http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/parallel-array-operations-in-java-8/240166287

https://blog.rapid7.com/2015/10/28/java-8-introduction-to-parallelism-and-spliterator/

Comment: Parallel operations are a good idea - however, there are billions of keys to check, so if you try an array-based solution I'd imagine you'll run into issues with the maximum size of an array.

Comment: He has to split and batch it, I don't think so it is straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

First things first:  You can't `println` billions of lines.  This will take forever, and it's pointless - you won't be able to see the text as it scrolls by, and your buffer won't save billion of lines so you couldn't scroll back up later even if you wanted to.  If you prefer (and don't mind it being 2-3% slower than it otherwise would be), you can output once every hundred million keys, just so you can verify your program is making progress.

You can optimize things by not concatenating Strings inside the loop.  Strings are immutable, so the old code was creating a rather large number of Strings, especially in the `enc` method.  Normally I'd use a `StringBuilder`, but in this case a simple character array will meet our needs.

And there's one more thing we need to do that your current code doesn't do:  Detect when we have the answer.  If we assume that the message will only contain characters from 0-127 with no Unicode or extended ASCII, then we know we have a possible answer when the entire message contains only characters in this range.  And we can also use this to further optimize, as we can then immediately discard any message that has a character outside of this range.  We don't even have to finish decoding it and can move on to the next key.  (If the message is of any length, the odds are that only one key will produce a decoded message with characters in that range - but it's not guaranteed, which is why I do not stop when I get to a valid message.  You could probably do that, though.)

Due to the way random numbers are generated in Java, anything in the seed above 32 bits is not used by the encoding/decoding algorithm.  So you only need to go up to 4294967295 instead of 9999999999.  (This also means the key that was originally used to encode the message might not be the key this program uses to decode it, since 2-3 keys in the 10 digit range will produce the same encoding/decoding.)

```
private static String tryToDecode4(String msg) {
    String returnedString = "";

    for (long i=0; i<=4294967295l; i++)
    {
        if (i % 100000000 == 0) // This part is just to see that it's making progress. Remove if desired for a small speed gain.
            System.out.println("Trying " + i);

        char[] decoded = enc4(msg, i);
        if (decoded == null)
            continue;

        returnedString = String.valueOf(decoded);
        System.out.println("decoding with key: " + i + " " + returnedString);
    }

    return returnedString;
}

private static char[] enc4(String msg, long key) { 
    char[] ansC = new char[msg.length()];
    Random rand = new Random(key); 
    for(int i=0;i<msg.length();i=i+1) 
    { 
        char c = msg.charAt(i); 
        int s = c; 
        int rd = rand.nextInt()%(256*256); 
        int s2 = s^rd; 
        char c2 = (char)(s2); 
        if (c2 > 127)
            return null;
        ansC[i] = c2;
    } 
    return ansC;
}
```

This code finished running in a little over 3 minutes on my machine, with a message of "Hello World".

This code will not work well for very short messages (3-4 characters or less.) It will not work if the message contains Unicode or extended ASCII, although it could easily be modified to do so if you know the range of characters that might be in the message.

Comment: Random is required to use a specific linear congruential generator (LCG) that is taken mod 2**48, so that the same seed produces the same output sequence portably. His encryption algorithm only uses the low-order 32 bits of this LCG, so the effect is that the high 16 bits of the seed don't affect the output.

Comment: So you're saying that's guaranteed, in every implementation, to work that way?  If so, I could include that in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's guaranteed, at least in official Java, in every implementation.

Comment: I have read your answer and it is indeed very good however I am unable to decrypt the below text (and many others like it):
撺曔幕䮮⟞༭뱜ﹴ䣥
胑￨ᧂ剿 㻧0Ӏꔙ홽
⥖ᑋ婆㋫⫚瀆佊∰熨䄣牊뗯瞼ᗶ샌鮆穔
듕่菬ﻈɸ쮋뷮ﱺ䚻㍤缲邰隸齦튼凫᧍滠렼茕펞鴨鯉݀



ﱈ촑ꄧ炔뗼︓濾岣⩔忟騿ᑓ䳮鈸⊉㨿剃澓씂ᡃ炖룚
贈࿡跑狔?䒼絸ﺭ뾸⚲鞭盛蠈륹╓鬙ᝰ⥳濫덠鿺㎦
橆蓏⇕﨔艠勤館枱ꁠ㰜ཕᑘ斋ೣ䆠恓맇ꎃ?蕆
ぶ?ꥶ럩ԙ﨡駲螿监륣퐾ꪇ쓠옘榪좞菸ᙠꇴ?酈쩸鉨諩

Ҝ뚄暟峐或ዳ閗胉뱽痙绳ૠ럽싦ᄴ䶾椗孽벏겾䥹鄌
ﵸ攗ႈ쭙﷑?ꈞ?䆜㢥퇑縲꾓饏犹⻦ߗⰌ豁쿢
琻槹닪᎜㓉㯷겶먖磎⪸퍤ૄ뜙ঽ䴴?앜ဎ䶟츸ឱᐒ籍鱩䉐㝘鲼
嘐蒵혼辮䄚㻸齈谗ꁅ㴥㫗졙?嵻ᾐ骕̑䏲뜲䜴⛩땙
ᚽﻐ?醪瓍䠐첾誗랷㽗퍺⋱慸ꑑ恭䡑吺᭢횈ﭦ赐횺?ڇ턨⨍突枫
਽ꓫ☝?⒵鱇徸?ླྀচ䁑鎴쒍ᎀꬋ?消鱏盡虺駘艏뙷觌淽匨뜶䦀䡍
澲頳誝⴦黌콢车忽ꅾ䊠ﺡ䍖ｌꖟ헐䰆ᅃ㬣虃奄⊏䑖댅⇚賜࿺긷큳
늭ﻍ쬫Ⰸﬤ䓯⎯氬㉵둿蓰곢呒쓪㺞⤽⒖斅䁺꛲쓽∖
ᴾ璧ጰ輕枈莔枤ࢋ䘐㳃᫽徢㧐䵊ᠳ賓႐컢鬰겒햏忩蒮墏ﶵࣁ玅챩“䁵﮴㽀绢ㄈ㹭

Comment: I think I have the answer!!! this text is encrypted with a different key for every single letter!!! I need to update my program to do that instead of relying on the whole text being encrypted with a single key

Comment: Nope, after trying to encrypt a single letter at a time I still get nonsense:
iq,xbWV\4rL'V{1ej`%9'^"Si$;aM,LU`AAl9A}3;~1=A:k4s?]2"0?we;minp}Lm0tyZkNWvUrDt`$|3&lwYhfpW)'/\*E

Comment: If it indeed uses a different key for each letter, then unless you know something else, it's impossible to decrypt.  As I mentioned in my answer, the program won't work well if you have 3-4 characters or less.  With 1 character it wont work at all.